# Retrieving data with axios---getting a 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm using `axios` to get data from a url and I'm receiving a 404 error. At first I thought the issue had something to do with CORS, but now I'm not 100% sure. This code *was* working with an earlier iteration of this project, but since I've started to migrate it I've had a lot of issues with getting the urls to work with axios.

#### JS snippet:

```
async function globalInitPromise() {
  const myObj = await loadMYProperties(); 
  const token = await permissionToCallMYAPI(myObj.hsHost);
  const myUser = new MYUser(myObj, token);

  const { mtoFolders, dcsFolders } = await getDocFolders(myUser, places);

  // const globalData = new globalData(...etc

  return { globalData, myUser };
}

export default globalInitPromise();

// class globalData code is here

class MYUser {
  constructor(myObj, token) {
    this.myObj = myObj;
    this.token = token;
  }

  userValidatedPostRequest(dataObj) {
    dataObj.Params.SAMAcct = this.myObj.currentAccount; 

    return axios
      .post(_BaseHost + "/MyAPI/api/Query/Post", dataObj, { 
             // _BaseHost is referenced elsewhere and is "https://etc.com"
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
          Authorization: this.token,
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "get,put,post,delete"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.statusText); // not being reached
          return response.data;
      })
      .catch(err => { 
          console.log(err) 
      })
  }
}
```

#### Console:

- [object Error]
- description: "Request failed with status code 404"
- [object Error]/response/config/url: https://etc.com/MyAPI/api/Query/Post

Comment: Getting a 404 usually have nothing to do with CORS, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are supposed to be set in server side, not in axios. Have you checked your destination url and `dataObj` are in correct format to be received by your server?.

Comment: @WilliamChong - Thanks, I didn't know that about 404-CORS and Access-Control. As for the destination url and `dataObj`, the format appears to be correct.

Comment: This does not seems to be a problem in this part of the code. You might want to try sending the same payload using other tools like curl or postman to confirm this is not a problem in the API side, and that you are actually using the correct url / payload first?